# To pass parameters to a thread and return a value, is the code below right?

Tags: django, python-2.7

## this is the thread:I try to add parameters to **init** function to pass parameters to the thread

```
class lookThread(threading.Thread):
data = []   
def __init__(self,userid):
    self.userid=userid
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
def run(self):
    lock=threading.lock()
    #lock
    lock.acquire()
    m=User.objects.get(userID=self.userid)
    userlist=[]
    userlist.append(m.userID)
    userlist.append(m.realName)
    userlist.append("")
    userlist.append(m.IDNumber)
    userlist.append(m.telNumber)

    lookThread.data= userlist
    #unlock
    lock.release()
```

## this is the function which invoke the thread.After the thread excutes, I want to get the userlist's value

```
def lookuserinfo(userid):
  new_thread=lookThread(userid)
  new_thread.start()
  resp = lookThread.data
  return resp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method can pass parameters to the thread, but can not return the variable 'userlist'. We can use data structure Queue to get 'userlist' value. First, initialize 'queue=Queue.Queue()' in function lookuserinfo(), pass 'queue' as a parameter to the thread,then use 'self.queue.put(userlist)' in the thread, finally use 'queue.get()' in the function. Moreover, Queue is thread safe.